# Strange fork() issue in C

Tags: c, mapreduce, operating-system, fork

This is an assignment for a basic mapReduce that finds the number of occurrences of a string in a text file.

I have a main that just calls spawnMapper().

The issue is that fork() == 0 but it won't go into that section and print "I made it!" or anything else. This is true if I set an int pid to what fork returns, or if I use fork directly.

Please help, it compiles and just won't work, I'm so confused.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "reducer.h"

//parent = greater than 1 child = 0

char fpeek(FILE *file);

void spawnMapper(char* keyword, char* fileLocation, int numberMappers){

    FILE *fptr;

    if((fptr=fopen(fileLocation, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("ERROR! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fptr);

    int mapperSize = size/numberMappers;
    fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numberMappers; i++){

        fptr = fopen(fileLocation, "r");
        int pToC[2]; //pipe parent to child
        int cToP[2]; //pipe child to parent
        if(pipe(pToC) == -1 || pipe(cToP) == -1){
            printf("pipe failure");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fork() ==  0) {
            printf("I made it!");
            fptr = fopen(fileLocation,"r");
            int threadSize = 0;
            int found = 0;
            while(fpeek(fptr) != EOF && threadSize < mapperSize){
                fseek(fptr, i*mapperSize, SEEK_SET);
                char* stringCheck;
                fscanf(fptr, "%s", stringCheck);                
                if(strcmp(keyword, stringCheck) == 0){
                    found += 1;
                }
                threadSize += strlen(stringCheck);
            }
            printf("found %d", found);
            //pipes to parent how many found 
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);   

}

char fpeek(FILE *stream){
    char c;

    c = fgetc(stream);
    ungetc(c, stream);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Put a "\n" at the end of your `printf` strings. `printf` is line buffered - it will not flush to stdout until a new line character is encountered. A common trap for the uninitiated as it appears as if certain code sections have not executed when it has.

Comment: You could also write data directly to stdout. I think that's unbuffered. Maybe try `char* buf="whatever to show on screen";ssize_t bytesprinted=write(STDOUT,buf,strlen(buf));`. Only problem is the formatting characters will not work as they would in printf.

Comment: you don't check if `fork()` call executed successfully. It may be failing and you don't notice it cause it goes through the `else` path.

Answer (score 0):

Kaylum stated in the comments that `printf` is line-buffered. This is a common misconception. It's `stdin` that's line-buffered; other functions (e.g. `putchar`) are affected, too. His solution is correct, nonetheless: Print a newline character to force the entirety of the line to be printed immediately.

Alternatively, `fflush(stdout);` will cause the text to be printed immediately *without* requiring a newline character.

It doesn't seem to me like Mike's advice would work, because the underlying problem is related to `termios` before your program even runs; the terminal is in cooked/canonical mode (meaning termios will wait until a newline before sending all of the data, so that it can handle things like backspace on behalf of the application). If you wanted to set the terminal to raw mode, meaning characters will be sent to your program as soon as the key is pressed, that's not relevant to C, but you might want to read [this page](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios/) and [this page](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios-termios3-and-stty/)...